# ASP.NET MVC Htmlhelper htmlAttributes doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

When I user this targ on a page like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It can work, But when I use like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobName, new { @data-provide="typeahead", })
```

then it can't work, because this attribute: data-provide, it have a symbol which is '-', how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the underscore character (the helper will translate this correctly and generate `data-provide="typeahead"`)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobName, new { data_provide="typeahead", })
```